# Comparison between `_if` suffix and `across` function

Tags: r, dplyr

I have a data (`df`):

```
set.seed(2)

df <- data.frame(x = replicate(n = 3, expr = sample(x = 1:3, size = 10, replace = TRUE)))
```

With `filter_if`:

```
library(dplyr)
library(magrittr)

df %>% 
  filter_if(.predicate = ~ is.integer(.), all_vars(expr = is_in(., '1')))

  x.1 x.2 x.3
1   1   1   1
```

The result is ok. But, with `across`:

```
df %>% 
  filter(across(.cols = ~ is.integer(.), .fns = all_vars(expr = is_in(., '1'))))
```

> Error: Internal error: Trace data is not square.

What is problem with `across`?

Comment: Could you add your session info or add the data with `dput`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can't reproduce your result but I think you need:

```
df %>% 
  filter(across(is.integer, ~ .%in% 1))
```

Result from both snippets:

```
 df %>% 
   filter_if(.predicate = ~ is.integer(.), all_vars(expr = magrittr::is_in(., '1')))
[1] x.1 x.2 x.3
<0 rows> (or 0-length row.names)
 df %>% 
   filter(across(is.integer, ~ .%in% 1))
[1] x.1 x.2 x.3
<0 rows> (or 0-length row.names)
```